# How to exclude 2 alphabetic character from a string in REGEX

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am trying to find the REGEX for this particular product code.

Description:

1. A valid product code must begin by a one of two digit number.
2. The number can't begin with 0
3. The number must be followed by a hyphen -
4. The hyphen is followed by a sequence of upper case
   letters conforming to the patterns AAA and BBB
5. AAA: string of any three upper case alphabetic characters except "I" and "O"
6. BBB string of any three upper case alphabetic characters in the range
   "A" to "D"

Examples:

- N-AAA
- NN-AAA
- NN-BBB
- NN-AAABBB

My problem is with the point 5) I mentioned. My solution so far is:

^[1-9]?[0-9]-[A-Z]**[^IO]**{3}?[A-D]{3}$

I am not sure about the part that I highlighted in my RE. I am looking to know if my solution is correct and if it is not, I would like to know the answer and the reasoning behind it.

Thanks,

Comment: It is not correct, since `[^IO]` matches *any* char but `I` and `O`. Also, why did you add `{#}`? And if you meant a hyphen after a number, why use `.`? So, `AAA` and `BBB` are 3-letter sequences each? Well, your requirements are not clear. Try [`^[1-9][0-9]?-(?:(?![IO])[A-Z]){3}(?:[A-D]{3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lhJAgI/1).

Comment: Are you using flex? (Alternatively, why flag the question [compiler-construction]?) Also, your examples seem to suggest that the number can be followed by either AAA or BBB or both. But that is not what your description says.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Negative Lookahead** `(?!([I]|[O]))` in your Regex. Please check this:

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]+\-(?!([I]|[O]))[A-Z]{3}[A-D]{3}
```

Old Update:

```
^[1-9]{1}[0-9]+\-((?!([I]|[O]))[A-Z]{3}[A-D]{3}|(?!([I]|[O]))[A-Z]{3}|[A-D]{3})
```

Updated regex:

```
^[1-9]{1}(|[0-9])\-([A-HJ-NP-Z]{3}[A-D]{3}|[A-HJ-NP-Z]{3}|[A-D]{3})
```

`^[1-9]{1}` Start with 1 to 9

`(|[0-9])` N or NN

`\-` hyphen (-)

`[A-HJ-NP-Z]` Avoid `I` and `O`

`([A-HJ-NP-Z]{3}[A-D]{3}|[A-HJ-NP-Z]{3}|[A-D]{3})` AAABBB or AAA or BBB

You can check it in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nprqe1/1).

Check my final update in [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/nprqe1/3/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since it can be AAA or AAABBB or BBB I guess that ^[1-9]{1}[0-9]+\-(?!([I]|[O]))[A-Z]{3}?[A-D]{3}? we should add "?" too right? I think your expression forces 6 chars after the hyphen. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you are using "|" instead of using "?" as I was mentioning on my previous comment. I would appreciate an explanation! Thanks :)

Comment: I've used `I` for `or`. `AAABBB` or `AAA` or `BBB`. `{3}?` and `{3}` both match exactly three times.

Comment: this will match `18-AIA`

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
^[1-9]\d?-(?:[A-HJ-NP-Z]{3}(?:[A-D]{3})?|(?:[A-D]{3}))$
```

[Regex Explanation and Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f1Ielo/4)